# Detect overlapping dates by group with R

Tags: r, date

Given a dataset

[image]

```
structure(list(intervention = c("Self Isolation", "Lockdown Low", 
"Lockdown Low", "Self Isolation", "Social Distancing", "Lockdown Low", 
"Social Distancing", "Handwashing"), date_start = structure(c(17897, 
17957, 18444, 17987, 17897, 17532, 17942, 18018), class = "Date"), 
    date_end = structure(c(17956, 18262, 18475, 18017, 17956, 
    18053, 18017, 18048), class = "Date")), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

How can I check if any "intervention" has overlapping dates? 
In this example, all interventions are good **but** "Social Distancing" and "Lockdown Low"

The ideal output would be a data frame with one intervention per line and a column filled with `TRUE`/`FALSE` depending if there is any overlapping for the intervention.

[image]

(Extra points for a tidyverse solution.)

Comment: what is your expected output.  Is it summarised output or creating a column

Comment: the ideal output would be a data frame with one intervention per line and a column filled with TRUE/FALSE depending if there is any overlapping for the intervention.

Comment: if you can update your post with expected, would be great

Comment: done, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Not clear about the values, `df1 %>% group_by(intervention) %>% summarise(flag = any(date_start >= lag(date_end, default = first(date_end))))`

Comment: should I order by `intervention` and `date_start`/`date_end` for this to work?

Comment: if you can update with the exact output you needed, it would be useful for crosscheckiing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do a `summarise`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    arrange(intervention, date_start, date_end) %>% 
    group_by(intervention) %>%
    summarise(overlapping = any(date_start < lag(date_end, 
         default = first(date_end)) & row_number() != 1))
# A tibble: 4 x 2
#  intervention      overlapping
#  <chr>             <lgl>      
#1 Handwashing       FALSE      
#2 Lockdown Low      TRUE       
#3 Self Isolation    FALSE      
#4 Social Distancing TRUE
```

Comment: Doesn't detect `Lockdown Low` overlapping if I add at the end of the dataframe `Lockdown Low, 01/01/2018,  02/01/2019`

Comment: How can we fix that?

Comment: @tic-toc-choc sorry, forgot to check this.  Do you have an updated dataset

Comment: @tic-toc-choc can you please update your post with the new data so that i can test