# How to find the proportion of IDs with overlapping interval dates in very large datasets in R

Tags: r, data.table, tidyverse

I've tried the various answers so far here:

- [Combining IRanges objects and maintaining mcols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55582833/combining-iranges-objects-and-maintaining-mcols)
- [Find all date ranges for overlapping start and end dates in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40647177/find-all-date-ranges-for-overlapping-start-and-end-dates-in-r)
- [Find groups of overlapping intervals with data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58152986/find-groups-of-overlapping-intervals-with-data-table/58155400#58155400)
- [Finding all overlaps in one iteration of foverlap in R's
  data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45558642/finding-all-overlaps-in-one-iteration-of-foverlap-in-rs-data-table)
- [Find dates within a period interval by group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44200364/find-dates-within-a-period-interval-by-group)
- [R Find overlap among time periods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34951356/r-find-overlap-among-time-periods)
- [Detect overlapping dates by group with R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61333135/detect-overlapping-dates-by-group-with-r)

Some work but are not very performant for very large datasets (8m-12m rows)

Just some sample code of what I've been trying:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)

size = 10000

df <- data.frame(
  ID = sample(1:round(size / 5, 0)),
  period = sample(c(5,10,30,45), size, replace = TRUE),
  start = sample(seq(
    as.Date('1999/01/01'), as.Date('2000/01/01'), by = "day"
  ), size, replace = TRUE)
) %>% mutate(end = start + period)


dt <-
  data.table(df, key = c("start", "end"))[, `:=`(row = 1:nrow(df))]

overlapping <-
  unique(foverlaps(dt, dt)[ID == i.ID & row != i.row, ID])
dt[, `:=`(Overlap = FALSE)][ID %in% overlapping, Overlap :=
                                          TRUE][order(ID, start)] %>% 
  distinct(ID,Overlap) %>% 
  count(Overlap) %>% 
  mutate(freq = n/sum(n))
```

This one works fine but if the dataset gets bigger it's either slow or there is a negative vector error:

`Error in foverlaps(dt, dt) : negative length vectors are not allowed`

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could directly join by `ID` in `foverlaps` and count number of overlaps :

```
size = 1e5

df <- data.frame(
  ID = sample(1:round(size / 5, 0)),
  period = sample(c(5,10,30,45), size, replace = TRUE),
  start = sample(seq(
    as.Date('1999/01/01'), as.Date('2000/01/01'), by = "day"
  ), size, replace = TRUE)
) %>% mutate(end = start + period)

dt <- data.table(df, key = c("start", "end"))[, `:=`(row = 1:nrow(df))]

setkey(dt,ID,start,end)
foverlaps(dt,dt,by.x=c("ID","start","end"),by.y=c("ID","start","end"))[
         ,.(noverlap=.N),by=.(ID,row)][
         ,.(overlap = max(noverlap>1)),by=ID][
         ,.(n=.N),by=.(overlap)][
         ,pct:=n/sum(n)][]

   Overlap    n   freq
1:   FALSE  547 0.2735
2:    TRUE 1453 0.7265
```

Performance comparison :

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(old(),new())
Unit: milliseconds
  expr      min       lq      mean   median        uq       max neval
 old() 672.6338 685.8825 788.78851 694.7804 864.95855 1311.9752   100
 new()  16.9942  17.7659  24.66032  18.7095  20.59965   63.3928   100
```

Comment: I'm away from my comp but how does that perform with 10m records? Just wondering if foverlaps still errors out.

Comment: On my comp, it takes below 20s for 10M rows. I get a memory allocation error for 100M rows.

Comment: What are your computer specs?

Comment: tablet PC, intel core i7, 16Gb

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! Can you also include the df to dt+row line of code in your answer, too? I got some errors before I found that was the issue.